# How to get textfield data without submit button ? Is it possible

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using 2 autocomplete in my php form.1st for getting company names (from mysql) & 2nd for getting product names of selected company (from mysql). For example if i select company "A" then i need to get all the product name of company "A" only in 2nd autocomplete textfield.

Note : (This is possible in select menu but i'm using autocomplete because i have a record of more then 200 companies)

My javascript code for autocomplete :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input#companyname").autocomplete({
source: [
          <?php
          while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($res))
          {
            $title = $rs['title'];
          ?>
          "<?php echo $title; ?>" <?php echo ", "; ?>   
          <?php
          }
          ?> 
         ]
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your title and body of your message don't seem to add up.

Comment: @ralfe My question is same like when u select country name from one drop down list, in 2nd drop down list u get the cities of that country.But in my case i m doing this with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the documentation for this JQuery .autocomplete pluging at http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ . So , an example would be:

```
var a = $('#query').autocomplete({ 
    serviceUrl:'service/autocomplete.ashx',
    minChars:2, 
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    maxHeight:400,
    width:300,
    zIndex: 9999,
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    params: { country:'Yes' }, //aditional parameters
    noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
    // callback function:
    onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
    // local autosugest options:
    lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'] //local lookup values 
  });
```

You will see that under params, you can specify additional data to send with the AJAX query. So, in your case, you would want to send the company name/id from the company input field with the autocomplete request for the products field. So you would have something like:

```
<input id='company_name' />
...
var company_name = document.getElementById('company_name').value;
...
params: { company: company_name }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a submit button but you will need a postback or an asynchronous callback--the submit button just does the first. If you wanted it to be similiar with the other autocomplete, look up Ajax calls from jquery.

Comment: I need submit button but at the end before getting values for product from selected company.

Answer (score -1):

This is the wrong way to go about it. You should create a separate PHP file that will out put your database results as [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  Then you can call upon this JSON file to do your auto complete in jquery.

As far as no Submit button you can try

```
$("input#companyname").keypress({
     // do your thing here
});
```

Comment: Why do people down vote and not leave a reason why? My answer should not have been down voted.

Comment: both autocomplete works correctly but the problem in 2nd autocomplete is that it works independently. it fetch all data from product table but in my case i need data of relevent company with a foreign key, @jason any ways thanks 4 reply

Comment: i didn't down voted but in your answer you are talking about `JSON` but in your codes, where you shows your `JSON` request??

Comment: I'm not using JSON, i fetch all values with simple mysql query @jogesh_p